# Thinktecture Authorization Server SAML Identity Provider

Tags: authorization, saml, thinktecture

I can easily associate Thinktecture Authorization Server with Identity Server.  Is there a way to associate Authorization Server as a relying party to an Identity Provider that only deals in SAML and not WS-*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization Server uses WIF and WIF doesn't support SAML.

Neither does identityServer.

You could go the route:

Authorization Server --> WS Fed --> ADFS --> SAML --> SAML IDP

or add a SAML stack to Authorization Server. This is non-trivial!